# Complex if statement on a SharePoint calculated column

Tags: if-statement, sharepoint, formulas

I am trying to create a formula for a calculated column in SharePoint 2013
My columns are: 
**W Certification,
V Certification,
Certification Sorting** (This is the calculated column)
If there are dates in both W Certification and V Certification, I want Certification Sorting to show a "3"
If there is only a date in W Certification, Certification Sorting Should show a "1"
If there is only a date in V Certification, Certification Sorting should show a "2"

This is the code I have tried: =IF([W Certification]=”Not Null”,”1”,IF([V Certification]=”Not Null″,”2”,IF(and [W Certification]=”Not Null″,”)([V Certification]=”Not Null″,”3”,)))) I still receive a syntax error.

Comment: Good to know. What have you tried? What's your issue?

Comment: =IF(ISBLANK([W Certification]),"EMPTY","1")=IF(ISBLANK([V Certification]),"EMPTY

Comment: This is giving me a yes or no.... I know it is not correct, but I am an extreme newbie and self taught

Comment: Please *edit* your own question to improve it.

Comment: Ok, so now I tried this,   =IF([W Certification]=”Not Null”,”1”,IF([V Certification]=”Not Null″,”2”,IF(and [W Certification]=”Not Null″,”)([V Certification]=”Not Null″,”3”,))))

Comment: EDIT the QUESTION, do **not** post unformatted unreadable code in comments. There is a "edit" hyperlink under your question. Also "I tried this" is not a problem statements. Describe what issue you are experiencing — by editing your question, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirements you've given, you're looking for a formula that resolves as so:

If `[W Certification]` is not blank and `[V Certification]` is not blank, show `3`, otherwise...

If `[W Certification]` is not blank, show `1`, otherwise...

If `[V Certification]` is not blank, show `2`, otherwise...

Show `0` (you didn't specify what you want to show in this case, so I went with zero)

You can accomplish this using Excel-like formula syntax, taking advantage of the `NOT()` and `ISBLANK()` formulas, and keeping in mind that the `IF()` formula is evaluated like so:

```
IF(condition, value if true, value if false)
```

With that in mind, your formula would look something like this:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK([W Certification])),NOT(ISBLANK([V Certification]))),"3",IF(NOT(ISBLANK([W Certification])),"1",IF(NOT(ISBLANK([V Certification])),"2","0")))
```